# Are there direct flights from Canada to Huatulco International Airport, Mexico during the summer?

Tags: air-travel, canada, mexico, hux

[Bahías de Huatulco International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bah%C3%ADas_de_Huatulco_International_Airport) (`HUX`) is close to some of my favourite parts of Mexico and I'm trying to search for flights landing there which depart from anywhere in Canada.

This is proving very difficult. Google returns lots of clickbait links which look like they have the ready answer but just lead to flight search engines that are not particularly good at finding these particular flights.

I've also tried the websites for the regional airlines listed in the Wikipedia article (`WS`, `RV`, `TS`, `WG`), but some seem broken, and some suggest the route is "seasonal" without offering further details.

I realize the high season will be when Canadians are taking a break from northern hemisphere winter, but I'm thinking of going to Mexico in the next couple of months from Canada.

Do any of these, or any other airlines offer **direct** flights to Huatulco during July and August?

(Flights which touch down in any US airport for any reason are not suitable. In any case, for the purposes of this question I'm not seeking alternatives.)

Comment: It doesn't look like it. I think you'll have to change in MEX

Comment: Looking at [FlightAware](http://flightaware.com/live/airport/MMBT/arrivals?;offset=0;order=actualarrivaltime;sort=DESC), it appears that there aren't that many flights into HUX at all, let alone from Canada.  In the past week (16-07-03 to 16-07-09), FlightAware lists a grand total of 39 flights into HUX:  one from Houston, one from Guatemala City, one from San Jose, and the rest from Mexico City.

Comment: Hmm. I know it's a quiet airport but I thought a lot of North Americans vacationing in the area got there that way, at least in the winter high season eight or nine years back.

Comment: From Canada the only direct flights go to Cancun, DF and Puerto Vallarta. If you don't want to transit through the US you'd have to change in DF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Air Canada Rouge has seasonal service from YYZ between December-March, search for flight [AC1512](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/ACA1512). You might not be able to book this flight or see its schedule this far in advance. AC would not let me attempt to book any flights from January 2017.

Air Transat has seasonal service to HUX [between December-March](http://www.airtransat.com/en-CA/Destinations-from-Canada/South/Mexico/Mexico-must-see-destinations/Huatulco?opentab=photo) from Edmonton, Regina, Vancouver, Calgary and Toronto.

Sunwing Airlines has [seasonal service](http://www.flysunwing.com/img/flysunwing-routes.pdf) to HUX from Vancouver, Calgary, Edmonton, Saskatoon, Regina, Winnipeg, Toronto, and Montreal, and will begin service from Victoria BC on 15 November 2016. Through sheer brute force, I learned the earliest date I was able to attempt to book from any city was exactly 15 November, and the latest return was 25 April.

WestJet starts their [seasonal service](http://www.westjet.com/vacations/en/destinations/destination-overview.shtml?id=DOAXHUX) on [23 October 2016 through approximately 30 April](http://www.westjet.com/en-ca/travel-info/flight-info/flight-schedules) with flights from Toronto and Calgary.

If you're going in the summer, though, plan on a connection in Mexico City or elsewhere. It looks like the earliest you'll get a nonstop flight is 23 October.